# Determining if a 2D system is LSI

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems

After a long time away from school, I'm a bit rusty and struggling with this question:

> Determine if the following discrete system is LSI: $y(m,n) = mn*x(m+n) + mn*x(m-n)$

So here's what I've done so far (note that the '*' means regular multiplication, I just added for better readability IMO).

1) Test linearity:

Let $r(m,n) = \alpha x_1(m,n) + \beta x_2(m,n)$, so $y(r(m,n)) = mn*(\alpha x_1(m+n) + \beta x_2(m+n)) + mn*(\alpha x_1(m-n) + \beta x_2(m-n))$

Now, evaluate $y(\alpha x_1(m,n)) + y(\beta x_2(m,n)) = mn* \alpha x_1(m+n) + mn* \alpha x_1(m-n) + mn* \beta x_2(m+n) + mn*\beta x_2(m-n)$

If this is correct, then the system is linear.

2) Test for Shift-invariance:
Let $g(m,n) = y(m,n)$, evaluate:

$g(m-m',n-n') = (m-m')(n-n')x(m-m'+n-n') + (m-m')(n-n')x(m-m'-(n-n'))$

Now evaluate:

$y(m-m',n-n') = (m-m')(n-n')x(m-m'+n-n') + (m-m')(n-n')x(m-m'-n-n')$

The only difference being the signal of the last $n'$, which makes it not Shift-Invariant.

It is my first time doing this process with a 2D system, so I'm really confused, especially with the system being on terms of $x(m+n)$ instead of $x(m,n)$

I'm following this [tutorial](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa06/cse166/LSI.pdf)

Thanks in advance for the help!